# getting error while generating key after uploading file into IPFS infura

Tags: infura, ipfs

I'm getting an error while generating key after uploading file into IPFS infura.

Sample code given below

```
var ipfsAPI = require('ipfs-http-client');
const ipfs = ipfsAPI('ipfs.infura.io', '5001', { protocol: 'https' });
var oldpath = files[property].path;
var uploadedFile = fs.readFileSync(oldpath);
const filess = [{
                    path: files[property].name,
                    content: ipfs.types.Buffer.from(uploadedFile)
             }];
 ipfs.add(filess, function (err, files) {

                  if (err || !files) {
                        return reject('upload failed');
                    };
 var obj;
for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    obj = { "id": i, "hash": data[i], "EID": formFields.EID };
    tt.push(obj);
}
ipfs.dag.put(tt, {}, (err, cid) => {
    console.log(cid.toBaseEncodedString());
    const adr = cid.toBaseEncodedString();
    var dTimeStamp = new Date().getTime();
ipfs.key.gen(dTimeStamp, {
type: 'rsa',
size: 2048
}, (err, key) => {
    if (err != null) {
        console.log(err)
        }

    console.log("ipfs Key: ", key.id + " key name : " + key.name);

    var keyVall = key.id;


ipfs.name.publish(adr, { key: keyVall }, (err, pVal) => {


        console.log("published hash : " + pVal);

        var ipfsHash = pVal.name;


    return resp.json({ status: 'SUCCESS', message: 'user has been created successfully', digitalID: pVal });
});
});
});

});
```

i'm getting a following error while generating key

```
"SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at streamToValue (C:\Service\node_modules\ipfs-http-client\src\utils\stream-to-json-value.js:25:18)
    at concat (C:Service\node_modules\ipfs-http-client\src\utils\stream-to-value.js:12:22)
    at ConcatStream.<anonymous> (C:Service\node_modules\concat-stream\index.js:37:43)
    at ConcatStream.emit (events.js:187:15)
    at finishMaybe (C:Service\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_writable.js:630:14)
    at afterWrite (C:Service\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_writable.js:492:3)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)"
```

Any leads will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Infura IPFS service only allows a small set of IPFS API methods through their Gateway so you cannot generate a key via `ipfs.key.gen`

[See Infura Documentation](https://infura.io/docs)

[image]

---

I would recommend to run your own IPFS node, especially if you want to generate and store keypair.

Comment: thanks for the information. Do you have any documentation to run own IPFS node on windows server?